# CMD net user - redirect output to a file

Tags: windows, command-line

When I run the command below, it opens `net1.exe`, displays output for less than 1 second and closes automatically. Also, I can't save this output to a file.

```
net user %username% /domain > output.txt
```

Comment: Have you tried just pasting that command into a  command window and seeing what it says? Without using your batch file? the `/domain` switch runs the query on the domain controller and you may not have permissions from the account running the batch.

Comment: @Narzard it displays seemingly normal information like `Full name`, `Last logon`, `Local group memberships` but it closes itself right away.

Comment: try changing your output to `"C:\folder\output.txt"`

Comment: It doesn't work either. It created the file but the file is empty. I think the issue with it is that it opens seperate process `net1.exe`. Because `gpresult /V >gpresult.txt` works fine.

Comment: try `net user %username% /domain > output.txt 2>&1`

Comment: Still empty file.

Comment: `net1.exe user %username% /domain > output.txt` try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to call net1.exe before letting cmd call it in a separate process.

`net1.exe user %username% /domain > output.txt`